# Two variables limit.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

**Exercise**. Discuss in $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ the value of following limit

$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y)=\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^2y}{(x^4+y^2)^\alpha(x^2+y^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}}.
$$

**Solution**. One has that $|f|\leq|x||y|^{1-2\alpha}$, which converges to $0$ if $\alpha\leq\frac{1}{2}$, and hence so does $f$. On the other hand, looking at the restriction of $f$ on the set $\{x>0, x=y\}$, one has

$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x,x)=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}x^{2-2\alpha}
$$

which equals $+\infty$ as soon as $\alpha>1$, and hence in this case the above limit does not exist (being for example $f$ identically zero on the coordinate axes). I am left with the case $\frac{1}{2}<\alpha\leq1$, which I tried to work out using polar coordinates but with no success.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

Let us take the polar coordinates not of $(x,y)$ but of $(x^2,y),$ i.e. $r>0$ and $\theta\in\left[-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right]$ such that
$$x^2=r\cos\theta,\quad y=r\sin\theta.$$
Then, as $r\to0,$
$$f(x,y)=\frac{r^{\frac32-2\alpha}\cos\theta\sin\theta}{\sqrt{\cos\theta+r\sin^2\theta}}$$
has no limit if $\alpha\ge\frac34$ (look for instance at $\theta=\pm\frac\pi4$), and converges to $0$ if $\alpha<\frac34$ (since $\left(f(x,y)\right)^2=r^{3-4\alpha}\frac{\cos^2\theta\sin^2\theta}{\cos\theta+r\sin^2\theta}\le r^{3-4\alpha}\cos\theta\sin^2\theta\le r^{3-4\alpha}$).